# can't assign to function callPython(parser-80)

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, neural-network, gekko

I am trying to pass the activation function argument to b.layer() from a list of strings.

I have tried eval('b.layer(parameters[1] = 3)')

'''

```
   #parameters = [layers,index_activation_function,nodes]

    parameters = [2,2,2]

    #Activation Functions
    a_functions = ['softmax','relu','tanh','sigmoid','linear'] 
    function = a_functions[parameters[1]]

    #NN
    b = brain.Brain(1)
    b.input_layer(1)
    b.layer(linear = 2)
    for i in range(layers):
        eval('b.layer(function=nodes)')
    b.layer(linear = 2)
```

'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is complete example that shows how to construct a string for the `eval()` function with Gekko. This isn't unique to Gekko and can be used for any string that you want to evaluate as an expression.

```py
from gekko import brain
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

# generate training data
x = np.linspace(0.0,2*np.pi)
y = np.sin(x)

parameters = [2,2,2]
a_functions = ['softmax','relu','tanh','sigmoid','linear'] 
function = a_functions[parameters[1]]
s = 'b.layer('+function+'=2)'

b = brain.Brain()
b.input_layer(1)
b.layer(linear=2)
eval(s)
b.layer(linear=2)
b.output_layer(1)
# train
b.learn(x,y)      

# validate
xp = np.linspace(-2*np.pi,4*np.pi,100)
yp = b.think(xp)  

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,y,'bo')
plt.plot(xp,yp[0],'r-')
plt.show()
```

This evaluates the string `b.layer(tanh=2)` by selecting the `tanh` activation function from your list of options. Here is the result of that script.

[image: Deep learning with Gekko]